# How to handle the Close Button click event on my popup window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my Master page.

```
PopUpWindow = function (titles, message) {
      document.getElementById('window').innerHTML = message;
      $("#window").dialog({
          resizable: true,
          height: 140,
          title: titles,
          width: 500,
          message: "something here",
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Close": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          }
      });
  };


<div id="window" style="display: none;">

        </div>
```

I can able to display the popup mesage perfectly.. 
My questions is..

I have this code in my controller.

```
 return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert('saved Successfully Added. Thank You.'); window.location='/ObnCategory/Index';" };
```

I changed the code to

```
 return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "PopUpWindow("saved","something here"); window.location='/ObnCategory/Index';" };
```

Here I am getting the popup perfectly but the problem is the popup closing automatically without clicing close button. due to window.location?

can any body tell me how to load the page after close button click..

PopupWindow is generic I can not keep window.location on popupwindow script?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `window.location` in the close handler...

```
PopUpWindow = function (titles, message, redirectURI) {
  document.getElementById('window').innerHTML = message;
  $("#window").dialog({
      resizable: true,
      height: 140,
      title: titles,
      width: 500,
      message: "something here",
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "Close": function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
              if(redirectURI) { //Only redirect if param is specified!
                  window.location=redirectURI;
              }
          }
      }
  });
};
```

Then

```
return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "PopUpWindow("saved","something here","/ObnCategory/Index");" };
```

Comment: PopUpWindow  this is my generic function..I can not do window.location in PopUpwindow funcation.. thanks

Comment: @kumar Okay than use some logic appending a param, I will update my post to show you a simple example.

Comment: @kumar I have updated the example, that way if you pass a URI to the `PopUpWindow` method it will execute the redirect on close of the dialog.  Good Luck!